# Ошибка: duplicate symbol ... in: ./Debug/tinyxml2.cpp.o в Codelite

Tags: c++, codelite

Уже была подобная ошибка, когда подключал `curl/curl.h`, тогда надо было ввести в Linker `-lcurl`, а-ля `g++ -o test filepath -lcurl` (Mac OSX). Понимаю, что ошибка из-за того, нужно подключить библиотеку в самом линкере, но не понимаю какую именно. Вот перечень инклудов:

```
#include "tinyxml2.h"

#include <new>      // yes, this one new style header, is in the Android SDK.
#if defined(ANDROID_NDK) || defined(__BORLANDC__) || defined(__QNXNTO__)
#   include <stddef.h>
#   include <stdarg.h>
#else
#   include <cstddef>
#   include <cstdarg>
#endif
```

`tinyxml2.h` - существующий файл в проекте, если что.

Подробней ниже:
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tinyxml2.h>
#include <tinyxml2.cpp>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace tinyxml2;
using namespace std;

static string buffer;

static int writer(char* data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string* buffer)
{
    int result = 0;
    if(buffer != NULL) {
    buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);
    result = size * nmemb;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_eng_utf8.xml");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROXY, NULL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res == CURLE_OK) {
            cout << "Downloaded" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "error: " << errorBuffer << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Оставьте комментарий пж";
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

tinixml2.cpp есть просьба загуглить ибо 2500 строк
tinixml.h аналогично

То что пишет терминал:

```
> /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j8 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ Money - Debug ]----------
/usr/bin/llvm-g++ -o ./Debug/Money @"Money.txt"   -lcurl -lncurses
duplicate symbol __ZN8tinyxml211XMLDocument8SetErrorENS_8XMLErrorEiPKcz in:
    ./Debug/tinyxml2.cpp.o
    ./Debug/main.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN8tinyxml210XMLPrinter5PrintEPKcz in:
    ./Debug/tinyxml2.cpp.o
    ./Debug/main.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN8tinyxml210XMLPrinter13PushAttributeEPKcx in:
    ./Debug/tinyxml2.cpp.o
    ./Debug/main.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK8tinyxml210XMLElement14Int64AttributeEPKcx in:
    ./Debug/tinyxml2.cpp.o
    ./Debug/main.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __ZN8tinyxml27XMLUtil7ToInt64EPKcPx in:
    ./Debug/tinyxml2.cpp.o
    ./Debug/main.cpp.o
ld: 227 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [Debug/Money] Error 1
make: *** [All] Error 2
====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Comment: Нет, эта ошибка не из-за того, что что-то надо подключать в линкере. Из-за чего она возникает - сказать невозможно, так как в вопросе не приведен пример, воспроизводящий эту проблему.

Comment: Пример добавлен

Comment: `#include <tinyxml2.cpp>` вот ваша проблема, не следует инклюдить исходники, вместо этого tinyxml2 надо как раз прилинковать

Comment: Дело в том, что на сайте tinyxml2 написано, что надо включить исходники в проект и не написано ни название библиотеки ни другого способа установки, а #include <tinyxml2> не видит. Документацию по установки читал и заверяю, что дело в инклудах в файле tinyxml2.cpp. -ltinyxml2 не работает

Comment: "включить исходники в проект" не означает инклюдить tinyxml2.cpp, это означает, что исходники бибилиотеки необходимо скомпилировать и слинковать вместе с другими единицами трансляции из вашего проекта. Это на самом деле бестолковой способ. Лучше соберите библиотеку отдельно и прилинкуйте ее. Ничего никуда устанавливать не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохо вы читали документацию. Отрывок из документации `Readme.md`:

> The top of tinyxml2.h even has a simple g++ command line if you are are Unix/Linux/BSD and don't want to use a build system.

```
g++ -Wall -DTINYXML2_DEBUG tinyxml2.cpp xmltest.cpp -o gccxmltest.exe
```

Вместо `xmltest.cpp` пишете `main.cpp`, вместо `gccxmltest.exe` название будущей вашей программы.
Из `main.cpp` уберите инклюд `tinyxml2.cpp`